# How to create a package written in a sqlfile (.sql)

Tags: sql, oracle, liquibase

I would like to create a package. I use SQLFile (*.sql)

when I write this :

```
liquibase --driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver --url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@serveur:port:BDD --username=cpt --password=mdp  --changeLogFile=D:\Travail\liquibase\essais_changelog\Mypackage.sql  update
```

I've an OK response

```
Starting Liquibase at lun., 12 ao¹t 2019 10:38:54 CEST (version 3.7.0 built at 2019-07-16 02:26:39)
Liquibase: Update has been successful.
```

BUT

the package is in error because the 2nd part of de file (the body) is not create

the file :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Mypackage IS

   PROCEDURE Init_pk;

END Mypackage;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Mypackage IS
       variable       IN VARCHAR2,

   PROCEDURE Init_pk IS
   BEGIN
         variable:="coucou"
   END;

END Mypackage;
/
```

Only the spec is created.
Not the body

Why ?

thanks
Michel

Answer (score 0):

Package body must be created but with compilation warning.

Following changes are needed in your package body call.

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY Mypackage IS
       variable      VARCHAR2(10); -- removed IN and ,

   PROCEDURE Init_pk IS
   BEGIN
         variable:='coucou'; -- replaced " with '
   END;

END Mypackage;
/
```

Cheers!!